# Split binary data file by AOB

Tags: binary-files, hex-editor

I have a file with the following magic AoB that acts a separator:

```
00 07 77 77 77 77 77 77 77 77 77 77 77 77 77 77
00 07 77 77 77 77 77 77 77 77 77 77 77 77 77 77
```

Is there any utility or quick way to split this file into many wherever this AoB occurs?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `magic AoB`?  Is it a text or binary file?  Providing a sample would be necessary, although I suspect I will make the question off-topic.  Perhaps it would become on topic for http://stackoverflow.com if you provide the code you tried to get it to work.  From the small amount of information, I would probably write a small PHP script to do the job.

Comment: As stated in the question, it is a binary file that contains these magic arrays of bytes that act as separators in this file. I wish to split the file based on the bytes highlighted in my post into multiple files

Comment: That would be easy to do in any language but I doubt that you'll find a tool that does it generically.  If you have any programming background, you should try to do it.  In PHP, you could use the `explode()` function to separate the contents based on that substring, since strings can be binary in PHP.